# Why does Scala compiler forbid declaration of a wildcard type as super type of a type parameter

Tags: scala, type-parameter, dependent-type, existential-type, type-bounds

I tried to create a type alias related to dependent type `_ >: a.type`.

The Scala compiler reports an error that I did not understand:

```
scala> def foo[A](a: A) = {
     |   type F = Function1[_ >: a.type, Unit]
     | } 
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type A)
 required: AnyRef
Note that A is unbounded, which means AnyRef is not a known parent.
Such types can participate in value classes, but instances
cannot appear in singleton types or in reference comparisons.
         type F = Function1[_ >: a.type, Unit]
                                 ^
```

If I replace `a: A` to `a: A with AnyRef`, it works:

```
scala> def foo[A](a: A with AnyRef) = {
     |   type F = Function1[_ >: a.type, Unit]
     | } 
foo: [A](a: A with AnyRef)Unit
```

Why?
What is the purpose of the restriction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/42.type.html

> **Any vs AnyRef**
>
> Currently there is a possibility to use singleton types in some contexts, but only on identifiers which point to a constant that conforms to AnyRef. This restriction is due to Any not having an eq method, which is what’s used for singleton type-equality check and pattern matching https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3558. This has been discussed on the mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/12h2TgDFnDM/Sq-EYi7VD7IJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/jsVlJI4H5OQ/BwdZT5hpKtsJ), and there is a consent that this needs to be done.

Comment: I still does not understand why it affects _ >: a.type. I thought a existential type like _ >: a.type would never be involved in type equality check.

Comment: I assume that the context is not considered when the safeguard is applied; let's hope that one of the Scala language gurus will clarify.